# Renewing facebook long lived acess token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to extend my facebook long lived access token.

These are the steps I followed

1. Created a short lived access token with facebook Api.
2. Generated long lived access token using the short lived access token.
3. Saved the expiry date and long lived access token in the database.

On the day before expiry date, I want to renew the long lived access token(with expiry of 60 days) without the Facebook login procedure.

Note : I tried to renew the token with the saved token in the database. But the issue and the expiry date is the same even though the access token is changing.

So how can i regenerate new token with extended validity without facebook login?

Comment: _“So how can i regenerate new token with extended validity without facebook login?”_ – you can’t. That was the whole _purpose_ of the deprecation of “offline access”, that apps can not go on acting on behalf of the user “for ever” any more. You want new token == you send user through login flow again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should make a dummy api call. The token expires if it is not used for 60 continuos days. So make a dummy use.